# В laravel 5 не работает Route::controller

Tags: php, laravel

Не работает `Route::controller('article','ArticleController')`, выдает ошибку `Method controller does not exist.`

Контроллер создавал через `artisan php artisan make:controller ArticleController`

Код контроллера:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ArticleController extends Controller
{
    // маршрут соответствует site.ru/article
    function getIndex()
    {
        $hello="Hello world!!";
        return view('mainpage',['hello'=>$hello]);
    }

    //маршрут соответствует site.ru/article/show
    function getShow()
    {
        $article='Моя статья';
        return view('article.show',['article'=>$article]);
    }

    // это POST запрос по адресу site.ru/article/save
    function postSave(Request $request)
    {
        //здесь сохраняем статью
    }
}
```

Что я упустил?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В [документации по обновлению](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/upgrade#5.2-deprecations) до Laravel 5.2 было предупреждение:

> The following features are deprecated in 5.2 and will be removed in the 5.3 release in June 2016:
>
> - Implicit controller routes using `Route::controller` have been deprecated. Please use explicit route registration in your routes
>     file. This will likely be extracted into a package.

Т.е. помечено устаревшим и удалено в 5.3. Прописывайте маршруты явно.

Comment: большое спасибо, буду внимательней!